# Strategy TP target round numbers

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to target round numbers as TP.

I have a grid which plot line to every round numbers with a price distance of 5$

1795.000
1790.000
1785.000
1780.000
1775.000
1770.000

Let's say that my long entry price is

1788.800

I would like to set as a general rule a TP target of 2 "round numbers" above the entry price for a long trade (2 below for a short trade), which in this case would be 1795.000.

TP targets are round numbers, but I do not enter long trade at round numbers, but based on price action, confluences etc.

So sometimes the entry price can be near the first "round number", or far from it, I don't care.

Could someone be so kind explain me how I can get (calculate) my targeted Profit ?

Thanks.

Hereafter the code of the script which plot the round numbers :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Round Number Zones", overlay=true)

line_col = input(color.gray, title ="Line color")
line_width = input.int(2, title = "Line width", minval = 1, maxval = 5)

line_count = input.int(title="Line count",  defval=10)
line_count_2 = math.floor(line_count / 2)

// Symbol 1 : EURUSD default
show_sym_1 = input.bool(title="Show", defval=true, inline="2")
sym_1 = input.symbol("EURUSD",title=" ", inline="2")
sym_1_steps = input.float(title="+/-",  defval=0.001, inline="2")

sym_1_sec = request.security(sym_1,timeframe.period, close)
sym_1_use_custom_price = input.bool(title="Custom Price", defval=false, inline="3")
sym_1_custom_price = input.float(title="", defval=1.08, inline="3")

// Symbol 2 : GOLD default
show_sym_2 = input.bool(title="Show", defval=true, inline="4")
sym_2 = input.symbol("GOLD",title=" ", inline="4")
sym_2_steps = input.float(title="+/-",  defval=5, inline="4")

sym_2_sec = request.security(sym_2,timeframe.period, close)
sym_2_use_custom_price = input.bool(title="Custom Price", defval=false, inline="5")
sym_2_custom_price = input.float(title="", defval=1900, inline="5")

// Symbol 3 : US30 default
show_sym_3 = input.bool(title="Show", defval=true, inline="6")
sym_3 = input.symbol("US30",title=" ", inline="6")
sym_3_steps = input.float(title="+/-",  defval=50, inline="6")

sym_3_sec = request.security(sym_3,timeframe.period, close)
sym_3_use_custom_price = input.bool(title="Custom Price", defval=false, inline="7")
sym_3_custom_price = input.float(title="", defval=3500, inline="7")


draw_line(sym, show, steps, custom, custom_price) =>
    if sym == syminfo.prefix + ":" +syminfo.ticker and show
        for i = 0 to line_count - 1
            price = custom ? custom_price : close
            step = math.ceil(price / steps) * steps + (i * steps) - (line_count_2 * steps)
        
            line.new(bar_index, step, bar_index - 1, step, xloc=xloc.bar_index, extend=extend.both, color=line_col, width=line_width, style=line.style_dotted)

draw_line(sym_1, show_sym_1, sym_1_steps, sym_1_use_custom_price, sym_1_custom_price)
draw_line(sym_2, show_sym_2, sym_2_steps, sym_2_use_custom_price, sym_2_custom_price)
draw_line(sym_3, show_sym_3, sym_3_steps, sym_3_use_custom_price, sym_3_custom_price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it is working :

```
// --- Calculation ---
stepValue = 5 // 5$ Interval between Round Numbers
stepNumbers = input(2, title="Number of Steps", group="Target Take Profit")
entryPrice = close[0]
roundNumber = stepValue * math.round(entryPrice / stepValue)
takeProfit = roundNumber + (stepValue * stepNumbers)
```

```
// === Take Profit ===
    strategy.exit("Long", comment="Long Take Profit", limit=takeProfit)
```